# How to save the output of a jupyter notebook cell (a pandas dataframe) as a high resolution picture?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

For normal plots I can set the `dpi` argument to generate a high resolution picture.

But for outputs of a cell such as in this picture, which is a output by displaying a pandas dataframe, how can I save it as a high resolution picture?

[image]

The above picture is from a screen capture but I dont really like it.

Comment: That specific detail, 'pandas dataframe', or something along those lines belongs in the title of the post to make it easier for people to find. As written, your title is more broad than you really want to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment [here](https://github.com/dexplo/dataframe_image) about [dataframe_image](https://github.com/dexplo/dataframe_image). As I now detail at my site about [dataframe2img](https://github.com/fomightez/dataframe2img), [dataframe_image](https://github.com/dexplo/dataframe_image) is a more mature solution.

[dataframe_image](https://github.com/dexplo/dataframe_image):

> "A python package for embedding pandas DataFrames as images into pdf and markdown documents."

Note specifically in the dataframe_image README under ['Exporting individual DataFrames'](https://github.com/dexplo/dataframe_image#exporting-individual-dataframes):

> "You may also export directly from the DataFrame or styled DataFrame using the `dfi.export` and `export_png` methods, respectively."

Comment: Thank you! This method really works well.